# Is it possible (if yes, then how) to provide the semantic segmentation results on the Original Size of the input image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, image-segmentation

[Just like this website](https://www.slazzer.com/), it does not matter what shape of image you provide them, instead of giving you a fixed size output, they'll segment your image and provide you the resulting image with original size.

**Hypothetically** speaking, let us we have a trained a Segmentation model (such as `U-Net`, `DeeplabV3+`, `UperNet` etc etc) and it was trained on image sizes of `512x512`(hypothetically) and gives me a resulting map of `512x512x3` (hypothetically 3 classes)

At the inference time, I got 2 different input images. first one having size of `1024,720` and second one of `1980x1080`. For inference, we'll have to resize both the images to `512x512` and we'll get a mask of `512x512x3` for both the images.

Now the question:

**How could I provide the users with the segmented map overlaid / superimposed on the original size**?

What I mean to say is that instead of returning image of `512x512` (with segmented map overlaid), Is it possible (if yes, then how) that I can return them the original size of `1024x720` and `1980x1080` **with the segmentation map overlaid**?

Someone please help me with this.

Comment: You can simply resize/upscale the images and segmentation map to the size you want using any of the classical algorithms (e.g. bilinear or bicubic upsampling) or if you want to get more advanced use a machine learning upsampling method.

Comment: @Oxbowerce So in that case, won't I lose information? I mean it is segmentation we're talking where boundaries have to be very strict and smooth and up sampling the predicted won't create any issue?

Comment: You would, but you will always be losing information when trying to get back an image that is larger than the image you have. The only way to not lose any information is to simply provide the model the images in the original size, and have the model predict/output a segmentation map of the full size you want, which is of course a trade off with the speed of the model.

Comment: @Oxbowerce  Accepting we don't care about speed, now what can be done? Can we pass in the images in their original form? Without resizing? Is that Possible? Or Pass in the image with **minimal** resizing (to avoid any hidden layers size mismatch)?

Comment: Depending on the exact architecture, but you could create a model architecture the outputs an array of the same size as its input and then simply pass in the full size image to a full size segmentation map out.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful